# Hecke’s 1938 IAS lectures - pdf or print copy?

Tags: reference-request

Just trying to locate a copy of Hecke’s 1938 lecture notes. I’m aware of the notes by Berndt that are based on Hecke’s lectures, but I really would like to find (pdf or for purchase) a copy of the original.

Worldcat entry, for reference: https://www.worldcat.org/title/lectures-by-erich-hecke-on-dirichlet-series-modular-functions-and-quadratic-form-spring-term-1938/oclc/8057061

Related: does anyone know the overlap, if any, between the IAS lecture notes and the GTM lecture notes published in 1983 (Lectures on the Theory of Algebraic Numbers)?

Comment: it is still under copyright, so you won't find it fully accessible online, however, you can browse through it via [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=eaIM9pHqR34C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Nice find! Thank you. I’ll have to try ebay or something to find a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second question of the OP, here are the table of contents of the two books, without any significant overlap.

[image]

[image]
[image]